# Laravel Snappy: Excess page

Tags: snappy, laravel-snappy, knp-snappy

In our application we implemented the laravel snappy for the export pdf. Everything is okay(i managed to export, getting all the values) except that I having an excess blank page.

**Controller**

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('registrations.export.export-pdf', $data)->setOption('footer-right','"page [page] of [topage]"');
return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf');
```

Question: Why I have an excess blank page?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it gives me an excess page because of the following css I have used in creating a page break number.

**Custom css**

```
.page{
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

So what I did, I changed the page into

**Custom css**

```
.page {
    overflow: hidden;
    page-break-after: always;
}
.page:last-of-type {
    page-break-after: auto
}
```